# AWS SSM "The security token included in the request is expired"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have a step of action of type aws:runCommand. It runs for 14+ hours. Everything runs successfully, but when the step attempts to complete, I get this error:

```
Automation Step Execution fails when it is verifying the command has completed. Get Exception from ListCommands API of ssm Service. Exception Message from ListCommands API: [The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AWSSimpleSystemsManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: ...; Proxy: null)]. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details
```

I've attempted to refresh the token by having the last step in my script be `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name_attached_to_instance> --role-session-name <some_name>`.

After this, I can run `aws ssm list-commands --command-id <command_id>` on the instance and I am not blocked by permissions. I see data data.

If the instance can talk to SSM, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.